# Can't Edit Products From Backend

Tags: product, product-edit

I did not make any changes recently related to this, but I can't edit or open any products from the Magento admin.

Here is the screenshot for what I see when I try to open a product.

Why am I not able to edit products?

[image]

Comment: They are in the database and showing on the frontend?

Comment: Yes. They are showing on frontend and people can buy products.

Comment: Im getting these error when i try to click kaydet(save) button

 "Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/store/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 507"

Comment: Check your exception/system log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

Using the url from the page you took the screenshot from. It should look something like this:

`example.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/key/[key]`

Then using a known product id and the key above, modify the url like this:

`example.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/[product_id]/key/[key]`

This should let you edit the product if it exists.